# Unique way to partition into two parts of equal weight

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization, partitions

A special case says it all ... Let $ w_1 < w_2 < \ldots < w_{12} $ be an increasing sequence of $12$ integers ("weights") such that the total weight $W=\sum_{k=1}^{12}w_k$ is even.

Say that $I \subseteq \lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,12 \rbrace$ is an exact subset iff
the sum $\sum_{k \in I}w_k$ equals $\frac{W}{2}$. My question is : is there
a sequence for which $ \lbrace 1,2,5,7,10,12 \rbrace $ is exact and is
the only exact subset (up to complementation) ?

Comment: A motivation would be welcome.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but isn't the complement of an exact subset also an exact subset?

Comment: Having said this, it seems that you have a linear function on $R^{12}$ with integer coefficients and you are trying to find its zeros on the set of vertices of a cube and you would like the set of zeros to consist exactly of a pair of opposite vertices. This does not seem hard to achieve.

Comment: @ Benoît : I encountered this problem trying to construct nontrivial examples in the context of partitions-with-weights problems that appear in recreational mathematics. The subset $\lbrace 1,2,5,7,10,12 \rbrace$ was chosen ``as random as possible".

Comment: @ damiano : I believe your linear-function-on-$ {\mathbb R}^{12} $ analogy only provides nondecreasing sequences instead of increasing sequences. If you insist that the sequence be increasing, you get an affine function instead of a linear function.

   Also, note that $ \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace $ can never be an exact subset.

Comment: The weights are the coeffs of a linear function. Rescaling the weights, it suffices to treat the case of rational coeffs, translating the *coordinates*, it suffices to consider the kernel. A subset *I* is exact if and only if evaluating the linear function on the vector of *1* and *-1* determined by *I* you get zero. Thus you are trying to find the zeros of a linear function on the vertices of a cube and you want the solution to consist exactly of a given pair of opposite vertices. If there is a linear function vanishing on the given pair, then clearly there is one vanishing only on that pair.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.  Consider the sequence

$100, 200, 201, 202, 500, 601, 700, 701, 801, 1000, 1194, 1200.$

It is easy to see that $X=\{1,2,5,7,10,12\}$ and $Y=\{3,4,6,8,9,11\}$ are exact.  Moreover, we claim that they are the only exact subsets. To see this, note that for every subset $X'$ of $X$, the sum of the corresponding sequence values is divisible by $100$.  However, for every proper subset $Y'$ of $Y$, the sum of the corresponding sequence values is not divisible by $100$.  Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are the only exact subsets.

Comment: 
  It's not quite clear to me that {1,2,5,7,10,12} is the only exact subset up to complementation. How did you construct your sequence ? 

Comment: Let X={1,2,5,7,10,12} and Y={3,4,6,8,9,11}.  Then for any subset of $X$ we have that the sum of the corresponding sequence values are 0 (mod 100).  However, for any proper subset of Y, the sum of the corresponding sequence values are non-zero (mod 100).  Thus, X and Y are the only exact subsets.  

Comment: Thanks Ewan.  Using the same technique it is easy to prove that if X is an exact subset of some sequence S, then there is another sequence S' such that X is the *unique* exact subset of S'.  For example, for sequences S of length 12, we can first multiply S by 10.  Then we can arbitrarily choose an index x in X and subtract 5 from the corresponding member of 10S.  We then can add 1 to the members of 10S corresponding to X -x to obtain S'.    

Answer (score 1):

Just an expansion on my comment. I will assume that exact sequences need to have half the number of indices of the whole sequence. Then a sequence is exact for some choice of weights if and only if it is exact for one weight. (This is already argued, both in my comment and in Tony Huynh's.)

The final question to be answered is when is a subsequence exact for some choice of weights. This is again very easy. A subset *I* of *{1,...,2n}* of size *n* obviously determines an increasing bijection $j_I$ between *I* and its complement. The subset *I* is an exact subsequence for some choice of weights if and only if the function $i \mapsto j_I(i)-i$ for $i \in I$ does not have constant sign.

Comment: Can't we handle the general case where exact sequences don't necessarily have half the indices?  That is, for some subset X of [n], let (X) be the sequence of elements of X in increasing order.  Letting Y by [n]-X, we have that X and Y are both exact for some sequence of length n if and only if (X) and (Y) are incomparable under the usual ordering of finite sequences (not necessarily of the same length) of integers.  

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a way of handling the general case, but I just have not thought about it. I do not know what is the "usual ordering of finite sequences"...

Comment: A sequence $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is less than or equal to another sequence $(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ if and only if there is an increasing map $f:[n] \to [m]$ such that $x_i \leq y_{f(i)}$ for all $i \in [n]$.  So, it is clear that if $(X) \leq (Y)$, then neither $X$ nor $Y$ can be exact.  I believe the converse is true as well.  